# Testing string against a set of vowels - Python

Tags: python, string, set, element

This is a module in my program:

```
def runVowels():
      # explains what this program does
    print "This program will count how many vowels and consonants are"
    print "in a string."
      # get the string to be analyzed from user
    stringToCount = input("Please enter a string: ")
      # convert string to all lowercase letters
    stringToCount.lower()
      # sets the index count to it's first number
    index = 0
      # a set of lowercase vowels each element will be tested against
    vowelSet = set(['a','e','i','o','u'])
      # sets the vowel count to 0
    vowels = 0
      # sets the consonant count to 0
    consonants = 0
      # sets the loop to run as many times as there are characters
      # in the string
    while index < len(stringToCount):
          # if an element in the string is in the vowels
        if stringToCount[index] in vowels:
              # then add 1 to the vowel count
            vowels += 1
            index += 1
        # otherwise, add 1 to the consonant count
        elif stringToCount[index] != vowels:
            consonants += 1
            index += 1
          # any other entry is invalid
        else:
            print "Your entry should only include letters."
            getSelection()

      # prints results
    print "In your string, there are:"
    print " " + str(vowels) + " vowels"
    print " " + str(consonants) + " consonants"
      # runs the main menu again
    getSelection()
```

However, when I test this program, I get this error:

```
line 28, in runVowels
    stringToCount = input("Please enter a string: ")
  File "<string>", line 1
    PupEman dABest
                 ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I tried adding a + 1 to the "while index < len(stringToCount)" but that didn't help either. I'm pretty new to python and I don't really understand what's wrong with my code. Any help would be appreciated.

I researched this error, all I found out was that EOF stands for end of file. This didn't help at all with resolving my problem. Also, I understand that sometimes the error isn't necessarily where python says the error is, so I double-checked my code and nothing seemed wrong in my eyes. Am I doing this the round-about way by creating a set to test the string elements against? Is there a simpler way to test if string elements are in a set?

**Question resolved. Thank you to all!**

Comment: Btw. you don't really need this to be in 2 separate print statements, 1 is enough: `print "This program will count how many vowels and consonants are"
    print "in a string."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested use `raw_input`. Also you don't need to do this:

```
while index < len(stringToCount):
      # if an element in the string is in the vowels
    if stringToCount[index] in vowels:
          # then add 1 to the vowel count
        vowels += 1
        index += 1
    # otherwise, add 1 to the consonant count
    elif stringToCount[index] != vowels:
        consonants += 1
        index += 1
      # any other entry is invalid
    else:
        print "Your entry should only include letters."
        getSelection()
```

Strings in Python are iterable, so you can just do something like this:

```
for character in stringToCount:
    if character in vowelSet : # Careful with variable names, one is a list and one an integer, same for consonants.
        vowels += 1
    elif character in consonantsSet: # Need this, if something is not in vowels it could be a number.
         consonants += 1
    else:
        print "Your entry should only include letters."
```

This should do just fine. Using a `while` is not necessary here, and very non-Pythonic `imho`. Use the advantage of using a nice language like Python when you can to make your life easier ;)

Comment: No it cannot, i.e. if it does the `else` part of the conditional statement will be triggered. But you could add another `elif` to check for special characters, e.g. `[' ', ',', '.', '!', '?']` and any other characters you can dream of.

Comment: Not a problem at all :)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're using Python 2. [Use `raw_input(...)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of `input(...)`. [The `input()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) will evaluate what you have typed as a Python expression, which is the reason you've got a SyntaxError.

Comment: Then I think my problem is not the one I stated because I originally had is as `raw_input`. When I use raw_input, I get this error: `line 51, in runVowels
    if stringToCount[index] in vowels:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`

Comment: @bij0ux: See the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can count the vowels like so:

```
>>> st='Testing string against a set of vowels - Python'
>>> sum(1 for c in st if c.lower() in 'aeiou')             
12
```

You can do something similar for consonants:

```
>>> sum(1 for c in st if c.lower() in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz')    
26
```

Comment: Why would you create a set of consonants if you don't even use it? :C

Comment: Python voodoo :) That's what I mean by making the most of a nice language.

Comment: This gives you the cardinality of the set of consonants, not the count of the number of consonants in the string..

Comment: And what if the raw input is, say, `1` or `?`? @kroolik You need to see if it's in consonants or vowels, if it's neither then you say that it's the wrong format.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke, no, it means that it has both no vowels and consonants.

Comment: Yes, but you need to see if it's in the consonants, simply checking if it isn't in vowels isn't enough.

Comment: @Claudiu: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @drewk: hmm weird i must have been seeing things. I could have sworn you did something like `sum(1 for c in set(st) if c in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")` .. never mind!

Comment: @ kroolik, in my program I initially didn't use a set for my consonants but another answer informed me that if I didn't, all other characters besides "aeiou", including numbers, would be added to the consonant count. Kinda like what Aleksander Lidtke was saying :)

Answer (score 1):

Also,

```
if stringToCount[index] in vowels:
```

should read

```
if stringToCount[index] in vowelSet:
```

Comment: This did make it work, thank you. I always miss petty details like that. A big downfall in terms of programming :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could solve the same thing:

```
def count_vowels_consonants(s):
    return (sum(1 for c in s if c.lower() in "aeiou"),
            sum(1 for c in s if c.lower() in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"))
```

To wit:

```
>>> count_vowels_consonants("aeiou aeiou yyy")
(10, 3)
>>> count_vowels_consonants("hello there")
(4, 6)
```

Python truly is grand.

---

The errors in your file run as follows (plus some suggestions):

```
stringToCount = input("Please enter a string: ")
```

This should be `raw_input` if you want what the user typed in as a string.

---

```
stringToCount.lower()
```

The `.lower()` method returns a *new* string with its letters lowered. It doesn't modify the original:

```
>>> a = "HELLO"
>>> a.lower()
"hello"
>>> a
"HELLO"
```

---

```
vowelSet = set(['a','e','i','o','u'])
```

Here you could just as easily do:

```
vowelSet = set("aeiou")
```

Note you also don't strictly need a `set` but it is indeed more efficient in general.

---

```
  # sets the vowel count to 0
vowels = 0
  # sets the consonant count to 0
consonants = 0
```

Please, you don't need comments for such simple statements.

---

```
index = 0
while index < len(stringToCount):
```

You usually don't need to use a while loop like this in python. Note that all you use `index` for is to get the corresponding character in `stringToCount`. Should instead be:

```
for c in stringToCount:
```

Now instead of:

```
    if stringToCount[index] in vowels:
        vowels += 1
        index += 1
```

You just do:

```
    if c in vowels:
        vowels += 1
```

---

```
    elif stringToCount[index] != vowels:
        consonants += 1
        index += 1
      # any other entry is invalid
```

Not quite right. You're checking that a character doesn't equal a set. Maybe you meant:

```
    elif c not in vowels:
        consonants += 1
```

But then there'd be no `else` case... Got to fix your logic here.

---

```
print "In your string, there are:"
print " " + str(vowels) + " vowels"
print " " + str(consonants) + " consonants"
```

The above is more pythonically written as:

```
print "In your string, there are: %s vowels %s consonants" % (
    vowels, consonants)
```

---

```
# runs the main menu again
getSelection()
```

Not sure why you're calling that there - why not call `getSelection()` from whatever calls `runVowel()`?

---

Hope that helped! Enjoy learning this great language.

Comment: I added a consonant set and used all your other tips in making my code more efficient. And I LOVE answers that help both my code and the display look pretty. ie the `print "In your string, there are:...` part :) Also, the getSelection() calls the "main menu", from which the user can either run that same program again, run a different program or exit the program completely.

Answer (score 0):

Bah, all that code is so slow ;). Clearly the fastest solution is:

```
slen = len(StringToCount)
vowels = slen - len(StringToCount.translate(None, 'aeiou'))
consonants = slen - vowels
```

...note that I don't claim it's the *clearest*... just the fastest :)